# android google map v2 drawing 1k circles performance issue

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to draw a lot of circles on google map v2 (about 1k). Unfortunatly, something is very slow and the map is laggy when drawing all the circles. I read a lot on stackoverflow but haven't found a fix yet.

**The circles represents a gps path (walking) so it makes sense here to have 1k or hundreads points to display (depending on zoom level of course).**

I guess i am creating to many objects causing performance issues with :

```
 CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
        circleOptions.center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).clickable(false).strokeWidth(2).strokeColor(Color.BLACK).fillColor(colorInHex)
                .radius(0.7);
 Circle circle = googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

Data are retrieve from a room db

```
   repository.getByLatLngBounds(projection.northeast.latitude, projection.northeast.longitude, projection.southwest.latitude, projection.southwest.longitude, new callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void loaded(List<MyPoint> points) {
                        if (points != null && googleMap != null) {
                          // iterate and draw points with circle
                        }
             }
});
```

Explanation :

1. I can't reduce the number of circle because i am already only targeting only the visibles bounds of the map
2. Data (coordinates for circles) are retrieve from an room db but actually take less than 1s get the result (from a asynctask)
3. I am not redrawing all points if the user is moving on the map (i keep track of all drawing points and if the point is already paint i do nothing)
4. I am using android google maps v2
5. I didn't tried with a custom drawable (performances should be worse).
6. The issue is not with marker displaying but drawing points (because i do not want to draw polygons here)

benchmark test numbers : 1227 points take 10s for drawing that sounds very slow isnt it ?

**Which is the way to improve performances in that case ? Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Even in visible bounds, users don't identify 2k worth of distinct objects. Without knowing what the circle represents or what level of zoom you are on, I would be using a heat map or weighted marker (circle) to cluster things together and reveal only on zoom-in / hide when zoomed-out (see video at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering)

Comment: It could be identify but user because i drawing "path" (but not with polygon, with single circles). As i know, clustering is to display marker and not a simple circle. The issue is not with marker but drawing points here. I have edited with more informations if you can help. Regards.

Comment: I think drawing a 2k circles to show a path is an overkill, you need to exclude points that are on the same line, and draw a path between the two edge-points of this set of points somehow.

Comment: it isn't an overkill because it is not exactly a "path". i can try to draw polylines instead but well is it no the purpose here. i also did benchmark as you can see it takes about 10s to display 1227 points that's sound very slow isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a fix. I checked about performances of polyline which is about 12x faster. So well, drawing circles is not possible if you have too many points.

So the idea is to draw a polyline and then to add a pattern with dots.

```
  PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
  polylineOptions.width(3);
  polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
  for(MyPoint point : pointsToDraw){
     polylineOptions.add(new LatLng(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude()));
  }
  Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(entry.getValue());
  // the key is here with the pattern
  List<PatternItem> pattern = Arrays.asList(new Dot());
  polyline.setPattern(pattern);
```